# Context menu colors

Tags: css

I'm trying to reproduce the macOS context menu :

[image]
[image]

For the moment, I tried to pick the color and play with the opacity but I can't get the real background-color with its opacity.

Where can I get them ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to reproduce it, instead of just *using* it, by letting the browser render a drop-down menu? Then, it'll be perfect, and you won't have to worry about looking ugly on other platforms.

Comment: I'm creating an angular app.
I'm also using this context menu : https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-contextmenu
And I want to have this kind of context menu (from macOS) on my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.9);
```

Answer (score 2):

with 2 layers you get almost exactly the effect, with one as mentioned by clement is shown below

[image]